# Fastboot is getting stuck while trying to flash CWM onto Nexus 4

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot

After successfully unlocking the bootloader of my new Nexus 4 using adb and fastboot I now want to install ClockworkMod Recovery onto my device.
Sadly it is not working properly. 
I am using Gnome Ubuntu 13.04 and installed adb and fastboot with apt.
While in fastboot mode my device is visible when testing with

```
$ sudo fastboot devices
002847af108bXXXX    fastboot
```

when I try to flash the ClockworkMod image recovery-clockwork-6.0.3.6-mako.img using

```
$ sudo fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-6.0.3.6-mako.img
sending 'recovery' (7814 KB)...
```

it gets stuck. I already waited for 40 minutes to complete but since the size of the image is around 8Mb I suppose it cannot take that much time and something is not working correctly.
Strangely also my USB-connected keyboard and Bluetooth-connected mouse are ignoring my inputs while fastboot is running.

I also tried renaming the .img file to recovery.img with the same result.
Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Try another USB port. It helped for me.

Comment: I am not sure whether to be happy or sad, that this worked for me, too...

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, but with Xubuntu 14.04 and a Nexus 10. Unfortunately, switching USB ports didn't help, although it did cause the terminal to pause a bit longer before displaying `sending 'recovery'`... Any ideas or more recent experiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I could fix it changing the usb port, it works!